# How to customize WooCommerce Breadcrumbs

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I wanted to remove the product name from the breadcrumbs and make it look like:

Shop / Category

So I added the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'tm_child_remove_product_title', 10, 2 );

function tm_child_remove_product_title( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ) {

if ( is_product() ) {

array_pop( $crumbs );

}

return $crumbs;


}
```

It worked but the category names become simple text with no links.

So, I tried to solve this with CSS:

```
    nav.woocommerce-breadcrumb:not(a) {
    color: transparent!important;
}

nav.woocommerce-breadcrumb a {
    color: #767676!important;
}
```

But my problem now is that the separator also becomes transparent. So now it looks Shop Category.

In sum, I need my breadcrumbs to be linkable, separated by "/" and without the product name.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I forgot to include the html code here:
Thanks! Unfortunately, it’s not in a list.

```
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb">
::before
  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/shop">Shop</a>
  &nbsp;/;&nbsp;
  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/product-category/snacks/">Snacks</a>
  &nbsp;/;&nbsp;Product Name
::after
</nav> 
</div>
```

Comment: We do have the same issue but I can't find the breadcrumb.php to try its solution. I'm using the Hello Elementor Child theme

Comment: See: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme - How to Edit Files](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1). In short: copy the existing file from the WooCommerce plugin to your own theme. The copied file will now override the WooCommerce default template file.